# How to compute $\text{Ass}_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> **Question:** Compute $\text{Ass}_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$.

We know that every number has a unique factorization into product of prime numbers, so $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_m^{k_m}$, but it looks not connect to the question. Anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank all!

Comment: What is the meaning of $Ass$ ?

Comment: [Associated prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Ass}\left(\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n \mathbb{Z}}\right) = \lbrace (p) \in \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}}: p\text{ is prime factor of } n\rbrace$.

Indeed, an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a divisor of zero on $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n \mathbb{Z}}$ if $\gcd(x, n) \neq 1$, that is, iff $x$ is a multiple of some prime factor $p$ of $n$.